# Classe que implementa Comparable deve comparar por um campo String em ordem lexicográfica

Tags: java, comparação

Como eu ordeno uma lista de pessoas pelo nome? Para entendimento, segue o código:

```
public class Pessoa implements Comparable<Pessoa> {
    
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String sexo;
    
    Pessoa(String nome, int idade, String sexo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }   

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pessoa outra) {
        if(this.nome.length() < outra.getNome().length())
            return -1;
        if(this.nome.length() > outra.getNome().length())
            return 1;
        
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Na classe de teste eu chamo o método `sort()`, porém, não está saindo lexicograficamente, por se tratar de nomes (strings) era o que eu esperava.

Sei que a classe `String` que implementa `Comparable` e neste caso estou lidando com um objeto `Pessoa`, mas se eu digo pra classe implementar `Comparable`, não deveria sair ordenado de forma lexicográfica? Como ficaria pra esses casos? Onde estou errando? Teria que carregar apenas strings na lista e não todo o objeto?

**Classe de teste:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TestaPessoa {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Joel", 34, "Masculino");
        Pessoa p6 = new Pessoa("Sebastião", 70, "Masculino");
        Pessoa p4 = new Pessoa("Ozeias", 41, "Masculino");
        Pessoa p5 = new Pessoa("Neuza", 59, "Feminino");
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Joabe", 33, "Masculino");
        Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa("Regiane", 37, "Feminino");
        
        
        List<Pessoa> pessoa = Arrays.asList(p2, p6, p4, p5, p1, p3);
        
        Collections.sort(pessoa);
        
        for(Pessoa p : pessoa) {
            System.out.println(p.getNome());
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Saída:**

```
Joel
Neuza
Joabe
Ozeias
Regiane
Sebastião
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) retorna o tamanho da string, então você está ordenando pela quantidade de caracteres do nome.

Se quer a ordem lexicográfica, compare as próprias strings. No caso, strings já possuem o método [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) implementado, então basta usá-lo:

```
public int compareTo(Pessoa outra) {
    return this.nome.compareTo(outra.nome);
}
```

---

Se quiser ignorar a diferença entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, pode usar [`compareToIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

---

Lembrando que, **caso a classe `Pessoa` não implementasse `Comparable`**, também seria possível ordenar pelo nome, usando um [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Collections.sort(pessoa, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) {
        return p1.getNome().compareTo(p2.getNome());
    }
});
```

Ou, a partir do Java 8, basta usar *method references*:

```
Collections.sort(pessoa, Comparator.comparing(Pessoa::getNome));
```

Comment: E para garantir que `nome` não vai ser nula, sugiro no construtor `this.nome = Objects.requireNonNull(nome);`

Comment: Ao invés de lançar uma exceção, poderia fazer assim também: `this.nome = (nome != null) ? nome : "";`

Comment: É uma boa pratica fazer essas comparações no construtor, ou seja, é comum pensando que não estou usando JPA? Se tivesse usando JPA seria feito apenas com @anotação no atributo certo?

Comment: @JGSILVA No construtor vc pode fazer a validação que for necessária para que o objeto não receba dados inválidos. Não existe isso de "boa prática", existe o que faz mais sentido em cada caso. A regra de negócio diz que o nome não pode ser nulo (ou vazio, ou tem que ter no mínimo X caracteres, etc)? Então valide sem medo :-)

Comment: @JGSILVA Leitura recomendada: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052)

Comment: @JGSILVA Só pra concluir (pois não é o foco da pergunta) eu prefiro a abordagem do Piovezan (se o nome é inválido, lança exceção e nem deixa criar o objeto). Deixar a pessoa com o nome vazio me parece estranho, faz sentido ter alguém sem nome? (Claro que vai depender dos requisitos, mas enfim, não vou me estender mais)

Comment: Obrigado, entendi perfeitamente sua resposta acima e já implementei. Entendi mais ainda quanto ao link que enviou, que podemos por validação no construtor e esta era a minha dúvida, já vi no link que podemos por sim e na sua resposta. O que eu quis dizer com JPA (usando hibernate na verdade), é que eu poderia por a validação no atributo nome (pra impedir que ele seja em branco) através da anotação @NotNull e apenas ali não mais no construtor usando a abordagem do Piovezan. Mas como você disse esta fugindo da pergunta principal, vou perguntando no decorrer dos estudos... Obrigado a vocês todos

Comment: @JGSILVA Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Comment: Resposta aceita :)